# QT Creator links different library than command line

Tags: opencv, linker, cmake, qt-creator, include-path

I have a problem I am unable to understand.
I am trying to code a project using openCV 3.1. I want to code inside the QT Creator Environment, because I'm used to that. I do not necessarily need any QT specific features at the moment, I'm working with Ubuntu 14.04.
The problem is, that whenever I try to build inside the QT Creator, it does not build with the following error, but it works if I build from the command line.

```
    10:57:36: Starting: "/usr/bin/cmake" --build . --target all
Linking CXX executable arucoTest
CMakeFiles/arucoTest.dir/PoseEstimator.cpp.o: In function `PoseEstimator::generateMarkers(std::string, int)':
PoseEstimator.cpp:(.text+0x56): undefined reference to `cv::aruco::getPredefinedDictionary(cv::aruco::PREDEFINED_DICTIONARY_NAME)'
PoseEstimator.cpp:(.text+0xb7): undefined reference to `cv::aruco::drawMarker(cv::Ptr<cv::aruco::Dictionary>&, int, int, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)'
PoseEstimator.cpp:(.text+0x1a9): undefined reference to `cv::imwrite(cv::String const&, cv::_InputArray const&, std::vector<int, std::allocator<int> > const&)'
CMakeFiles/arucoTest.dir/PoseEstimator.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::~String()':
PoseEstimator.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringD2Ev[_ZN2cv6StringD5Ev]+0x14): undefined reference to `cv::String::deallocate()'
CMakeFiles/arucoTest.dir/PoseEstimator.cpp.o: In function `cv::String::String(std::string const&)':
PoseEstimator.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv6StringC2ERKSs[_ZN2cv6StringC5ERKSs]+0x69): undefined reference to `cv::String::allocate(unsigned long)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [arucoTest] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/arucoTest.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
10:57:36: The process "/usr/bin/cmake" exited with code 2.
```

So it is some kind of linker error. When I inspect my cmake file and output, I see this:

```
Running "/usr/bin/cmake /XYZ/arucoTest '-GCodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles'" in /XYZ/arucoTest/testbuild.
-- OpenCV library status:
--     version: 2.4.8
--     libraries: opencv_videostab;opencv_video;opencv_ts;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_photo;opencv_ocl;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_legacy;opencv_imgproc;opencv_highgui;opencv_gpu;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_contrib;opencv_calib3d
--     include path: /usr/include/opencv;/usr/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /XYZ/arucoTest/testbuild
```

As you can see, it only finds openCV 2.4.8, which I still need because of old ROS Indigo projects. However, if I execute the exact same cmake file and build from the commandline, it works perfectly:

```
username@pc:/XYZ/arucoTest/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- OpenCV library status:
--     version: 3.1.0
--     libraries: opencv_xphoto;opencv_xobjdetect;opencv_ximgproc;opencv_xfeatures2d;opencv_tracking;opencv_text;opencv_surface_matching;opencv_structured_light;opencv_stereo;opencv_saliency;opencv_rgbd;opencv_reg;opencv_plot;opencv_optflow;opencv_line_descriptor;opencv_fuzzy;opencv_face;opencv_dpm;opencv_dnn;opencv_datasets;opencv_ccalib;opencv_bioinspired;opencv_bgsegm;opencv_aruco;opencv_viz;opencv_videostab;opencv_videoio;opencv_video;opencv_superres;opencv_stitching;opencv_shape;opencv_photo;opencv_objdetect;opencv_ml;opencv_imgproc;opencv_imgcodecs;opencv_highgui;opencv_flann;opencv_features2d;opencv_core;opencv_calib3d
--     include path: /usr/local/include/opencv;/usr/local/include
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /XYZ/arucoTest/build
veith@roethlinLT:/XYZ/arucoTest/build$ make
Scanning dependencies of target arucoTest
[100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/arucoTest.dir/PoseEstimator.cpp.o
Linking CXX executable arucoTest
[100%] Built target arucoTest
```

As you can see I'm building in 2 different folders, because I found that if I cmake in the same folder, it does not work, even if I remove everything in that folder and cmake again from the command line. Also notice, that it finds 2 different include paths depending on where I start the cmake from.

My makefile looks like this (not very crazy), I'm using this exact same file for both cases.

```
project(arucoTest)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)

find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

message(STATUS "OpenCV library status:")
message(STATUS "    version: ${OpenCV_VERSION}")
message(STATUS "    libraries: ${OpenCV_LIBS}")
message(STATUS "    include path: ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}")

set(HEADER_LIST PoseEstimator.h)
set(SRC_LIST PoseEstimator.cpp)
add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SRC_LIST})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

Using ccmake and the QT build in inspection window, I see that the OpenCV_DIR variable is set to 2 different things:                                                                       On command line:

```
 OpenCV_DIR                       /usr/local/share/OpenCV
```

In QT Creator:

```
OpenCV_DIR                           /ust/share/OpenCV
```

How do I set this to automatically select the right folder inside QT Creator as well? I really have no idea what could cause this!
Thanks!

Comment: Cache variable `OpenCV_DIR` is set by searching with command [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) (in *config* mode). While search mechanism is fully deterministic (it is described in the doc), it uses some envorinment variables which may differ under your shell and QT Creator. Just a guess, QT Creator may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` *environment* variable to contain `/usr`. For choose specific OpenCV installation, just set `OpenCV_DIR` cache variable accordingly and rerun configuration process.

Comment: That worked great, thanks. I'm still curious where I can find the environment variable in QT and why it might be different. I'll accept your answer if you post it as one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cache variable `OpenCV_DIR` is set by searching with command [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html) (in *config* mode). While search mechanism is fully deterministic (it is described in the doc), it uses some *envorinment variables* which may differ under your shell and in QT Creator.

Just a guess, QT Creator may set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` environment variable to contain `/usr` directory, so it finds an installation under `/usr` before one under `/usr/local`.

For choose specific OpenCV installation, just set `OpenCV_DIR` cache variable accordingly and rerun configuration process.